# Formal = totalitarian?: Why was this closed?

Tags: discussion, support, on-topic-off-topic, close-reasons, closed-questions

I beg for your forgiveness if [Formal = totalitarian?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/33512/8712) offends, but I would like to request its reopening. While it's from my law preparation book, my question concerns English, why was it 'closed as off-topic'? Would someone please advise how to improve or emend it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to improve this question by removing the parts that I didn't think were relevant, focusing it on the question about *formal* and *totalitarian*.  Ideally, we shouldn't have to read all of the potential answers to the test questions and so forth unless they're actually related to the question itself.

However, the question is still unanswerable in its current state because you've neglected to quote the relevant portions of the essay.  "The formal state" is defined in the next paragraph.  The author expects you to read the *entire* passage before picking an answer.  Don't read just one paragraph and try to come to the right conclusion.

Comment: Thank you. I've added more of the passage. Does it help?

Comment: @LePressentiment Yes, I've just voted to reopen.

Answer (score 3):

There's a difference between English Language Learning, and Reading Comprehension Assistance. Just because you are asking about an English test question doesn't mean  your question "concerns English."

The onus is on ***you*** to make sure these questions are directly pertinent to *language*, and not just reading comprehension.

As an aside, please try to avoid extraneous spaces, like these:

> better **defi ned** than formal states .. on the basis of this **compari son**"